# MauiCommunityToolkit Popup doesn't hide when request

Tags: c#, maui, maui-community-toolkit

In my `NET8` `MAUI` application, I like to display a loading message when the app opens a new page and loads the data to display. Because I use ViewModel, I implemented a [PopupService](https://puresourcecode.com/dotnet/maui/open-a-loading-popup-from-maui-viewmodel/) following this post and the code is

```
public class PopupService : IPopupService
{
    Page page { get; set; }

    public void ClosePopup(Popup popup)
    {
        if (page == null)
            page = Application.Current?.MainPage ?? throw new NullReferenceException();
        popup.Close();
    }

    public void Init(Page page)
    {
        this.page = page;
    }

    public void ShowPopup(Popup popup)
    {
        if (page == null)
            page = Application.Current?.MainPage ?? throw new NullReferenceException();
        page.ShowPopup(popup);
    }
}
```

When in a page I want to display a `LoadingPopup`, I call this code

```
var loading = new LoadingPopup();
popupService.ShowPopup(loading);
```

The `LoadingPopup` is defined with the MauiCommunityToolkit

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<toolkit:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
                    x:Class="LanguageInUse.Views.Popups.LoadingPopup">

    <VerticalStackLayout WidthRequest="350" Margin="30" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="True" Margin="25" />
        <Label Text="Loading..." Style="{StaticResource labelLoading}" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</toolkit: Popup>
```

The `LoadingPopup` is displayed as I expect. The issue is when I want to close the popup: for that I call the `ClosePopup` function.

The issue is not always the popup is close although I call the function. To remove the popup, I have to top or click on the screen. A consequence of that is that the components are not clickable because - I think - the layer from the popup is still displayed probably with a transparent background.

[image]

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Did you try to set a button for the PopUp Page, and bind the close event to the butthon, like the [Programmatically closing a Popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/popup#programmatically-closing-a-popup) introduced?

Comment: could it be that you are calling your `ClosePopup` method from a background thread and hence nothing happens? Have you tried force calling it on MainThread.

Comment: No, I haven't. I will try and let you know

Comment: [Programmatically closing a Popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/popup#programmatically-closing-a-popup) provides two methods(`Close()` and `CloseAsync()`) to close the Popup. Did you try to use these two methods to close the Popup respectively?